# Dismiss View Controller Not Working For iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Dismiss View Controller is not working in iPad, OS is 8.4.1
But this is working on iOS 9 & iOS 10

```
 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: its weird ! i didn't tested in iOS8 need to check

Comment: Can you kindly provide other necessary details along with scenario and how you are presented code?